# How to separate Upstream and downstream logs in Envoy?

Tags: istio, envoyproxy, python-envoy

I am using Envoy as a proxy in my architecture and I want to separate the access logs for upstream and downstream traffic. I am currently using Envoy version 1.18

I am using the following code in my configuration:

```
access_log:
         
          - name: envoy.file_access_log
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.file.v3.FileAccessLog
              path: /var/log/envoy/access-outbound.log
              filter:
                 // some filter


           - name: envoy.file_access_log
             typed_config:
               "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.file.v3.FileAccessLog
               path: /var/log/envoy/access-inbound.log
               filter:
                 // some filter
```

I was thinking if there is any field like `filter_direction`  which can filter the logs based on their direction (Inbound/Outbound).

Can someone provide me with a sample configuration to achieve this or guide me on how to achieve it?